# What is the wrong judgement in reviewing queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I was reviewing queues some minutes ago, as I think it can help the community, and I encountered two things which I do not really understand nor agree:

This first image was an accepted review. But I was shocked to see the difference in opinions from the reviewers.

[image: this one]

I mean, I have sometimes seen 3 "Looks OK" and 1 "requires editing" or even "unsalvageable". But in this case, there are 2 "editings", 2 "unsalvageable" and the rest OK. How can this abysm of a difference exist? With this picture, I started to doubt about my "judgement" and that maybe I was harming the community by my poor judgement (or maybe the others were wrong, which can be).

I upvoted the question, but in Stack Overflow I see a lot of reticency to do upvotes. It's like people don't want to give upvotes, quite strangely. In the Japanese Community, for example, any effort shown is worth an upvote! In SO is quite different.

But then I encountered a question which I did not see wrong (maybe because I lacked some knowledge).

[image: This one]

I have asked several questions, so I know how to ask a good, minimal, etc question.

I have used mongodb, so I did not find it a weird question .And the question was closed by the community! I mean, that means I was completely wrong, but I do not really understand how I was so wrong and, if that is the case, in other cases I have helped with "Looks ok" or flagging, did I really do it right?

Comment: "this question was deleted as spam or offensive". I am going to make a guess that the user was deleted as a known spammer.

Comment: Is database migration on-topic on SO? It's a system administrator task and not a programming problem. Btw.: The question wasn't **closed** by the community user. It was **deleted**.

Comment: @BDL I mean the answer to this question is "**make backups you fool of a Took!**". Definitely not a programming problem.

Comment: But judgements are made for the questions or answers. I have no chance to now if the user is a known spammer. The question itself looked like a lack of concept which needed to be cleared by any answer which could be helpful... @Gimby

Comment: Regarding the review results of the mentioned triage queue:  this sadly happens a lot. In my experience most users who vote "looks ok" are way to lenient about actual issues in a question, especially users with rather low reputation score (i.e. lower experience with the site) and don't bother to search if the question is a duplicate or not. And most of the "requires editing" votes are from users who don't know what "requires editing" actually means.

Comment: As for what I know, you can do so by programming, and for what I understood, he lacked concepts and needed some guidance, not a coding answer but an insight, which looks good to me... @BDL

Comment: M.K. questions looking fof general advice and guidance are not good for S.O. It may be that the cultural difference between SO.jp and SO is significative in this case. But that kind of question is very much frowned upon here.

Comment: Maybe you are choosing "looks ok" too often. Remember that the reason we have the review queues is to detect problematic content, so you should expect to find troublesome posts fairly often. "Looks ok" or "No action needed" should happen less often than any of the alternatives (including "skip").

Comment: "What is the best way to do X" should be a smell that there's something wrong with the question.

Comment: <sarcasm> *There is an easy solution to your question, which is apparently the preferred one for current moderators: Ban everybody who returns "Requires editing." from the review. Then, you asymptotically end up with only two classes, and the situation will look a bit less paradox. Next month, we start banning reviewers wo choose "Looks OK.".* </sarcasm>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[First Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22277136)** (You choose Looks OK)

This question is not "Looks OK". There is at least an "i" that is not capitalized and a blank after a comma is missing. So you should have selected at least "Requires Editing". I'm not from the Android field, so I cannot really judge if the question is close worthy. I would at least expect an image of what the user sees and what they expect to see.

**Second Review** (You choose Looks OK)

This question is off-topic. Server administration is not a programming problem and should thus not be asked on SO.

While looking for the review links, I also noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22277375) review, where you marked a request for a off-site resource as "Requires Editing". "Requires Editing" means that anyone can fix the problem by editing it and is suboptimal for off-topic questions.

Comment: Okay, that clears up most of it. Thanks a lot. On the last review you link, I chose Requires Editing in the sense that if the user edits the question adding some soruces like code or images, it can be a good question. I mean, why would you mark it to edit, and not edit it, if you can do it yourself? But that was a good answer for my question. I'll be more carefull in the next ones or choose "Skip" if I am not sure!

Comment: "Requires editing" means that anyone (but not only OP) can edit the question into shape. What requires editing basically does is that it pushes the question into the "Help and Improvements" queue. But for this specific question, even with all the edits in the world a "I'm looking for a tool" question will still be off-topic. You might want to read [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue)

Comment: @M.K "required editing" doesn't mean "OP should edit in order to make it a good question" (chose "unsalvageable" for that case), instead it means "the question is ok and on-topic, but some random user can fix formatting or typos".

Comment: Most of this is OK, but a few random typos do not Require Editing. The FAQ says that button is (among other things) for when someone will need to "Overhaul its *substantial* spelling/grammar/formatting errors". Later on, it says, "If it's a halfway decent question but not amazing, or if some editing would be nice to clean up some minor errors or rough spots, but it's just about as answerable without any, just hit Looks OK."